# How to manage huge number of UPDATE statements in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I just executed more number of update statements(500) in SQL Server like below

```
update di_artikel 
set beschaffungszeit_intern = '14'
where nr = '0.600.910.0L09631'

update di_artikel 
set beschaffungszeit_intern = '14'
where nr = '0.600.910.1L09631'

update di_artikel 
set beschaffungszeit_intern = '14'
where nr = '0.600.910.2L09631'

update di_artikel 
set beschaffungszeit_intern = '14'
where nr = '0.600.910.4L09631'

 update di_artikel 
 set beschaffungszeit_intern = '14'
 where nr = '0.600.910.5L09631'

 update di_artikel 
 set beschaffungszeit_intern = '14'
 where nr = '0.600.910.8L09631' ......  more
```

I got the result like
 (1 row(s) affected) or
 (0 row(s) affected).

0 rows means some materials(nr) are not executed.
Reason for that is some materials in not in di_artikel table.

BUT I NEED TO FIND UN SUCCESSFUL MATERIALS, HOW I NEED TO GET?

Comment: Maybe with a case when statment. Can you more explicit on your question.

Comment: you may check after each update `if @@ROWCOUNT = 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte
as
(
select 
* from table where nr in ('keep all your inputs')
)
update cte
output inserted.*
set nr ='whatever value'
```

inserted.* gives you only what is updated value,which helps you in understanding  which rows are updated

Comment: I didn't get this, could you please elaborate?